# Publish to TestFlight menu not enabled in monodevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, adhoc, ipa, testflight

I am using Monodevelop v3.0 and Monotouch v5.2.11. When I try to publish my app to testflight, "publish to TestFlight" menu is not enabled.
I searched through the web found few requested to check "Build ad-hoc/ enterprises Package"  in IPhone IPA options and build the app.

I tried all the possibilities. Still the menu "Publish to TestFlight" menu is not enable. I think I am missing some basic step.
Can anyone help me plz?

I am using Monotouch evaluation version. Will testflight work in evaluation version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Testflight service only works with applications built for **devices**.

The evaluation version of MonoTouch only works for the **simulator**.

You need a full license (and applications built for devices) to test Testflight integration in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I am trying to purchase Monotouch professional edition. Is this enough or I need to purchase enterprises licence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Professional is enough to use Testflight. You'll also need a developer account from Apple (required to sign applications before uploading them to devices). If you plan to use an Enterprise developer account (from Apple) and want every feature of it then you'll need MonoTouch Enterprise.